# woocommerce_sort_product_tabs() expects an array

Tags: functions, woocommerce-offtopic, tabs

I am trying to add a custom tab to Woocommerce Product ; I have tried with this code snippet in functions.php :

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_product_tabs', 'woo_new_product_tab' );
function woo_new_product_tab( $tabs ) {
// Adds the new tab
    $tabs['desc_tab'] = array(
        'title'     => __( 'Additional Informationsss', 'woocommerce' ),
        'callback'  => 'woo_new_product_tab_content'
    );
}

function woo_new_product_tab_content() {
    // The new tab content
    echo '<p>Lorem Ipsum</p>';
}
```

But it is showing this error  :

```
Notice: Function woocommerce_sort_product_tabs() expects an array as the first parameter. Defaulting to empty array
```

Do anyone has encountered this error before or have an idea how to deal with it ?

Thanks in advance

Comment: you are not returning anything in your filter, 
you should `return $tabs` after apending new tab array

Comment: woocommerce and other 3rd party product/plugin/theme dev support questions are offtopic here and not in this stacks scope

Answer (score 0):

i think you most return $tabs in your woo_new_product_tab function

try this :

```
function woo_new_product_tab( $tabs ) {
// Adds the new tab
$tabs['desc_tab'] = array(
    'title'     => __( 'Additional Informationsss', 'woocommerce' ),
    'priority' => 10,
    'callback'  => 'woo_new_product_tab_content',
);
return $tabs;
}
```